# Client fails TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

A client is trying to connect to my website using a client certificate. However, they get a 400 error. They gave me their public certificates excluding root CA in a .crt file.

This is the access log:

```
52.215.251.216 - - [07/Sep/2023:09:44:02 +0200] "POST /dome/Bundle?_format=json HTTP/1.1" 400 224 "-" "HAPI-FHIR/6.8.0 (FHIR Client; FHIR 3.0.2/DSTU3; apache)"
```

There is no error log in my Nginx error log file. This is my config file:

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.nl;
    root /var/www/website/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";



    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/1_nl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/1_nl/certificate.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/2_nl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional;

    location /dome/Bundle {

            
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/website/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_cert;
            fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

       
    ## OCSP Stapling
    resolver 127.0.0.53;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/1_nl/ssl-bundle.crt;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.nl;
    return 301 https://mywebsite.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mywebsite.nl;
   
    return 301 https://mywebsite.nl$request_uri;
}
```

However, client told me they get this error:

```
termination_state = CD
```

Now on [this website](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#8.5) it says what the CD code means, namely

> CD   The client unexpectedly aborted during data transfer. This can be
> caused by a browser crash, by an intermediate equipment between the
> client and haproxy which decided to actively break the connection,
> by network routing issues between the client and haproxy, or by a
> keep-alive session between the server and the client terminated first
> by the client.

I'm not sure whether this means it's the client's problem, because this is the error the client gave me.

In PHP I use this code `if ($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY'] == 'SUCCESS'){ echo 'handshake successful'; }`
to check if the handshake was successful.

Does anyone have any idea why the connection is not working? The client tells me they do it like this with all other customers and everything works 100% from their side.

More importantly, how do I error log this?